# NodeJS RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I use socket.io

**Error**

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

when calling `socket.disconnect()`;

Comment: You made a booboo, somewhere you have some sort of infinite loop adding to the call stack

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/socket_io/nZ528BvOYsQ) may help. Basically says to disable logging.

`io.set('log level', false)`

Didn't help in my case. I'm seeing this while emitting data and it's related to the `has-binary-data` dependency `socket.io/node_modules/has-binary-data/index.js:42`.